# Google Maps API, can I change country names?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API v3 for a map on my Website, and am setting the laguage to French.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=fr">`

The problem is that Google has done a poor job for the French translation of country names. To remedy this, I'm wondering if I can rewrite all country names. I have searched and searched, but alas, nothing but style-based modifications it seems. Can this be done? If so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to hide all the labels on the map and add your own.  Once you hide the existing labels (using a [styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)), you can add labels you like to the map using [infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html).  This won't work if you have lots of labels, but if it is just the country names it should be OK.

Comment: thanks. I will test to see how feasible this is given my amount of labels.