# google maps country names

Tags: google-maps-api-3, label

Is there a way to override country names in google maps api v3. The case for me here is to remove/replace the "Macedonia" label and leave only the "FYROM" one or replace it with "FYROM". So is there  a way to tamper with this point? I have to note that i have implemented the solution of placing a dummy image over this part of the map as a layer but the outcome was not the desired one.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API, can I change country names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861105/google-maps-api-can-i-change-country-names)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) to remove all the country names.  Then add them back with a label (like [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html))